# Make non-human readable gmail password in python code

Tags: python, passwords, gmail

I have the following code :

```
username = 'username@gmail.com'
password = 'password'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
```

I'm seeking for a way not to write hard-coded the password.  GETPASS requires interactively password prompt and i dont want it. 
Is there an alternative way to achieve this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can obfuscate the password but no, there is no foolproof way to do it. One way would be to keep it in a separate file/database that the other users can't access.

Comment: If you're only protecting yourself from humans reading, then you could try base64 encoding, however, it is very very easy for a program to decode base64 data.

Answer (score 0):

There's loads of ways to obfuscate or encrypt but the problem you're going to run into is that whatever it is, if it's in your code someone who has access to your code and can read it, can unencrypt it.

I'd advise storing it in a database in an encrypted then base64 encoded form. Base64 encoding will basically mean you don't get any weird characters your database might balk at.

Here's a routine that will encrypt and decrypt things for you in AES

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key ="" # ASSIGN 32 ALPHANUMERIC CHARACTERS TO THIS VAR
iv = "" # ASSIGN 16 ALPHANUMERIC CHARACTERS TO THIS VAR
def enCrypt(string):
    """
    Encypts in AES 256bit and then base64 encodes it for database entry
    """
    encFormat = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    return base64.b64encode(encFormat.encrypt(string))
def deCrypt(string):
    """
    Decodes the string fron base64 then decrypt the resulting AES string
    """
    destring = base64.b64decode(string)
    encFormat = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    return encFormat.decrypt(destring)
```

It's fairly self explanatory but if you have a password like "bobbins"

```
encrypted = enCrypt("bobbins")
```

and to decrypt

```
deCrypt(encrypted)
```

But I highly recommend storing in a database even if it's something small and basic like sqlite. For this I recommend looking into the SQLAlchemy module

Answer (score 0):

How about the private, public key attempt?

Encrypt the password with your public key and write that hard-coded in your programm.
Save the private key somewhere defined on your computer (not comitting it or sharing any kind).
And then for the login in the program, encrypt your password with your private key.

It will only work on your pc (where you have the private key), but maybe thats enough for you.

Have a look at PyCrypto: https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what you're getting at here—if it's simply not wanting to share a password you could setup an “application-specific” password, but that would still allow others access your account…

OAuth would allow you to set a scope such that someone with the “password” could send email, but not access other account activities, or even read mail, depending on your wishes.

If you're not set on SMTP google allows 1,000,000,000 “quota units” per day via the GMail API.

## GMail Python API

### Initializing Service

You could use OAuth authentication to allow sending email via the **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send** “[scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)”.

If you decide to go this route, perhaps using a [python library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth), you should be able to send a message using Google's example:

### Sending Message

```
"""Send an email message from the user's account.
"""

import base64
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes
import os

from apiclient import errors


def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
  """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
  """
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
               .execute())
    print 'Message Id: %s' % message['id']
    return message
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error


def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}


def CreateMessageWithAttachment(sender, to, subject, message_text, file_dir,
                                filename):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.
    file_dir: The directory containing the file to be attached.
    filename: The name of the file to be attached.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEMultipart()
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject

  msg = MIMEText(message_text)
  message.attach(msg)

  path = os.path.join(file_dir, filename)
  content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(path)

  if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
    content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
  main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
  if main_type == 'text':
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
    fp.close()
  elif main_type == 'image':
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
    fp.close()
  elif main_type == 'audio':
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
    fp.close()
  else:
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
    msg.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()

  msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
  message.attach(msg)

  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```